# if n^3 has a fast rate of growth than n^2 i.e. O(n^2)<O(n^3) then why is n^2 better than n^3?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, analysis

n2 has a lower order of growth than n3. I get it that we can verify it graphically or we can put values like 1,2,3... 
n3 attains a value in less time than n2, then why do we prefer n2 of n3?

Comment: What does "better" mean to you and what is the context? For the context of time or space complexity, "better" most definitely should not mean "grows faster" (the opposite, in fact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> n3 attains a value in less time than n2

`n^3` does indeed attain a value *on the Y axis* in *less space on the X axis* than `n^2`.  But what is that value it's attaining?  What do these axes represent?  Let's look at an actual graph of this:

[image]

(In this graph, `O(n^3)` would be a curve between `O(2^n)` and `O(n^2)`.)

The Y axis is *operations*, not *results*.  And the X axis is *elements*, not *time*.  So your `O(n^3)` algorithm is going to perform *more operations*.  In every case the *results* are the same.  The metric being measured here is how many operations are performed on a given set of elements in order to achieve the result.

`n^3` climbs the graph faster than `n^2`, which means it performs more operations to compute the same results.  More operations on the same hardware means it takes more time.

We prefer `O(n^2)` algorithms over `O(n^3)` algorithms because we prefer algorithms which calculate the same results with fewer operations.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are measuring use of resources (time or space), which are costs, not performances, so lower is better